# Typescript error using a variable string to locate the value in an object

Tags: javascript, typescript, indexing, javascript-objects

I am trying to use as a variable to locate a value in an object, basically console.log(myobj.name) but use a variable instead of name e.g.

```
const myProperty = name:string
console.log(myObj[myProperty])
```

## full details below (including interfaces)

The code runs but I get  the following error in VSCODE.

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Details'.
```

below is the code the very last line is the one where I get the typescript error (using strict types)

```
interface Details {
  id:number,
  name:string,
  email:string
}

interface Items {
  [key: string]: Details[],
  } 

const items: Items = {
  "blackberry":[
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'John Doe',
      email: 'john@doe.de'
    },{
      id: 2,
      name: 'Brad',
      email: 'lorem@ipsum.com',
  }
  ],
  "orange":[{
      id: 4,
      name: 'Barry',
      email: 'john@doe.de'
    }
  ]
}
const myName:string = "name" 
const myIx:string = "orange"
// console.log(items[myIx])
console.log(items[myIx][0].name)
console.log(items[myIx][0][myName]) // code runs but TS error here in VScode
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the correct type for `myName`:

```js
const myName: keyof Details = "name"
```

This also has the advantage, that you get a compile error when you have a typo, e.g. this will fail:

```js
const myName: keyof Details = "Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript sees a string passed with `object[str]` as being able to all kinds of values. You can set the `myIx` to an enum to force it to be one of the actually existing keys within the `interface` or the quick and dirty fix can be to cast it to any like this `(items[myIx][0] as any)[myName]`